# Appropriating ID for all lines inside polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, spatial-join, overlapping-features

I have 12 Polygons with a lot of lines in every Polygon. The Polygon have each its own `"ID"`. I would like to add the `"ID"` of the polygon to the lines it is containing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Open the attribute table of the line layer and create a new field or update an existing. Make sure it has the correct fieldtype. Since QGIS 3.16 you can then use this expression:

```
array_first(overlay_within('polygons',"PolygonID"))
```

Replace `'polygons'` with the name of the polygon layer and `"PolygonID"` with the fieldname containing the ID's of the polygons.

---

If you use a QGIS version older than 3.16 you can use `aggregate()` like:

```
array_first(aggregate('polygons','array_agg',"PolygonID",filter:=within(geometry(@parent),$geometry)))
```

---

[image]